# Python - how to get the services that run on my computer

Tags: python, linux, service

I want to create a simple program in python that save all the services that run on my ubuntu linux computer. I want it to be as simple as possible when save maximum information about the services.
What is the best way to do so? Is there a library that I can use?

thanks.

Comment: What's your distro?

Comment: @Jahângir Ubuntu linux - edited my question.

Comment: Then the answer below shall work :)

Comment: @Jahângir thanks :) I'm just curious, but there is a reason for this answer not to work in different linux system? I guess the answer is different shell, am I right?

Comment: Yes, the utility `service` is available in most distros, but some of them might have tinkered with it and for them you need to figure out the proper way to ask the list of services from the OS. For one, I'm using a Mac right now and although Macs are *nix based, the command doesn't work, but `launchctl list` does the trick ..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('service --status-all', stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess
sp = subprocess.Popen("service --status-all", stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
print 'Services output: {0}'.format(sp[0])
```

You could also change the command `service --status-all` to any other shell supported command you would like.

Hope this helps.